# How to enable Spring Framework 3.0.5 to support RabbitMQ?

Tags: java, spring, amqp, spring-rabbit

I am working in a legacy project where Spring Framework 3.0.5 was used. Now I need to use RabbitMQ to meet some business requirement. I have followed all docs available in official links.

In there, all suggests to use spring annotation such as `@Listener` annotation for executing a method when message is arrived in queue. The problem is, these annotations do not work with Spring Framework 3.0.5 .

So, how can I make them working without changing the spring version. Is there any manual way to create such listener that will auto trigger a method call when there will be message in the queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't ask the same question in multiple places; it wastes your time and ours.

As I answered on GitHub:

> Spring 3.0 is has not been supported for several years; even Spring 4.3.x will not be supported after this year.

> The last version of spring-amqp to use Spring 3.0.x (3.0.7) was the 1.1.4.RELEASE from 2013. There was no annotation support back then; you either had to implement `MesssageListener` or you could use the `MessageListenerAdapter` to invoke POJO methods with converted payloads.

> https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.1.4.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html#d4e258

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. There are so many false information and blurry instruction that I was almost sick of it. Now I am very much clear about it. Thank you again!